# "This is particularly since..."

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis

Recently I came across this sentence:

> [... allegations that such information had been used elsewhere]
>   *This is particularly since you were given access to the information.*

I have been trying to think of why I think it is wrong and I guess maybe it is just missing a *so*:

> *This is particularly **so** since you were given access to the information.*

But my question is whether the original sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: @200_success why, he says right in the question what he thinks is wrong with it.  He thinks it's _grammatically weird_.

Comment: We need the whole preceding sentence. Probably, 'S1, particularly since ...' will sound more natural.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misconception. There's no error per se.

Comment: There are no issues either of grammar or meaning, esp., if we see the *is* as the operative word (verb) here.

Comment: @Kris "There is nothing wrong" would be an answer; it doesn't make a question off-topic.

Comment: @Kris Oh, could you please elaborate on this? "Particularly" is an adverb and "This is [adverb]" sounds pretty ungrammatical to me. And I think that could be the reason why OP came up with that question.

Comment: @Em1 I think Shoe had given a good answer below. It seems to be an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Particularly* is one of the group of words that *The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* (p592) calls *partial restrictive focusing modifiers*. Others include *primarily*, *mainly* and *chiefly*. The CGEL notes that:

> It is characteristic of focusing adverbs that they modify a wide range
>   of constructions,

and includes clauses in the list of such constructions.

This leads to the conclusion that the sentence *This is particularly since you were given access to the information* is grammatical.

Similar examples from Google include:

> This is particularly since there is no time limit for abortion under
>   this section.
>
> This is mainly since I did not find a way to apply specific css rules.
>
> This is primarily since steel is not an element on the periodic table.
>
> This is chiefly since it's easy to handle and form this hairdo.

Answer (score 1):

'Particularly' is an adverb and needs to modify a noun or adjective. No noun or adjective, however, comes after 'particularly' in this sentence. That is the the word that is missing.

Saying 'particularly so' makes it technically correct but is still poor writing. I could suggest a better word but I would need the rest of the article.

Comment: "Particularly relevant" seems like it might fit here.

Comment: Given what I can read of the passage, I think you're right.

Comment: Unfortunately they are confidential information so I cannot post the whole paragraph here. But knowing the context, I would say the sentence is more along the lines of 'This is especially true given that ...

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence is nonstandard. *This is ____....* needs a complement, and complements are nouns (or pronouns, as *so* would be if used here) or adjectives.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @TimLymington What is not?